# ReactJS: Gunzip not working like in node.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to uncompress a file from S3. The code works completely fine in node.js, but getting data from S3 works, but uncompressing it with `ungzip` doesn't, and gives me the error below.

package - node-gzip

Code:

```js
s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    ungzip(data.Body)
        .then((uncompressed) => JSON.parse(uncompressed.toString('utf8')))
        .then(json => json)
})
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: incorrect header check
    at index.js:17
    at Gunzip.onError (index.js:210)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:152)
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (index.js:355)
    at Zlib.push../node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/binding.js.Zlib._error (binding.js:283)
    at Zlib.push../node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/binding.js.Zlib._checkError (binding.js:254)
    at Zlib.push../node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/binding.js.Zlib._after (binding.js:262)
    at binding.js:126
    at Item.push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:153)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:123)
```

Comment: Maybe the browser decompresses the file automatically?

Comment: It didn't, I think it's best if I just uncompress it in the nodejs backend, instead reactjs client, because it's working in nodejs